# Capture Return Code of task as exit code for Ansible Playbook

Tags: bash, automation, scripting, ansible

Let's start from the very beginning:

- I have a bash script which returns different exit codes accordingly with the error reported.
- I launch that script with ansible BUT, when the script fails the ansible-playbook exit code which I check with "echo $?" is different from the exit code of the remote script.

I know Ansible has the following exit codes:

```
*0* -- OK or no hosts matched

*1* -- Error

*2* -- One or more hosts failed

*3* -- One or more hosts were unreachable

*4* -- Parser error

*5* -- Bad or incomplete options

*99* -- User interrupted execution

*250* -- Unexpected error
```

So the question is if there is any way to have the return code of the task as the exit code of the Ansible Playbook.

Regards,

Comment: You answered the question yourself by listing all the ansible RCs and their meaning => No. You get ansible command RC not what-ever-task-rc-you-ran-in-your-playbook. (Which one would you choose by the way if there are several with error control and such ran on a variable number of host that will not all fail ?) You can register the result of a task (e.g. `register: my_cmd` on your shell/command task) and get the rc of that command in that var with `{{ my_cmd.rc }}`

Comment: I know I can get the rc in a variable or even write the output to a logfile. And that Ansible has its own exit codes. What I am asking for is a workaround, because I need to evaluate the exit of the playbook as I was doing with the script.

Comment: Which script (in the potential a list of several script your could run in different tasks) running on which host (in the potential list of all hosts in your inventory that could pass/fail randomly) ? IMO you are using the wrong tool here. If you just need to run a bash script on a remote host and get the RC, simply run your script directly through ssh and you are done.

Comment: Well, if I just wanted to run a bash script on a remote host I would have already done it without asking any question here. Don't take things for granted, there is more context on this issue that I could explain here. But in my case, Ansible is the way to go for automation having in mind all its integration with other tools via plugins (notifications to Grafana, logstash among many other things)

Comment: Just for the record, there are some more Return Codes, [6, 8, 143, 255](https://jwkenney.github.io/ansible-return-codes/).

Answer (score 2):

> Q: *"Is any way to have the return code of the task as the exit code of the AnsiblePlaybook?"*

A: There is no such option. It's possible to use ansible-runner instead. See [Artifacts](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy).

- Use [set_stats](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_stats_module.html#set-stats-set-stats-for-the-current-ansible-run)  to customize the playbook's output.
- Use [ansible-runner](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/standalone.html#using-runner-as-a-standalone-command-line-tool) to run the playbook.
- Get the customized output from [artifacts/ID/stdout](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy).
- Create wrapper. FWIW, see as a hint [arwrapper.bash](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-runner/blob/master/contrib/arwrapper.bash) and [Ansible Runner Usage Examples](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#ansible-runner-usage-examples).

Answer (score 0):

ansible-runner is complex and doesn't work on macOS.

Here is the end of my playbook.yml:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Prepare VM
      script: ./logic.bash &> ~/logic.bash.log
      register: returned
      ignore_errors: yes
    - name: read log
      shell: |
        cat ~/logic.bash.log
      register: file_content
    - name: print log
      debug:
        verbosity: 2
        msg: "{{ file_content.stdout }}"
    - name: print RC
      debug:
        msg: "RETURN_CODE: {{returned.rc}}"
```

And here is the code I use in a script called run.bash to execute the playbook and check the RC of the task.

```bash
ID="${RANDOM}"
ansible-playbook -vvvv -i ${BUZYFORM_INVENTORY_FILE} playbook.yml > /tmp/"${ID}"
RC="$(grep RETURN_CODE /tmp/${ID} | cut -d"|" -f2)"
cat /tmp/"${ID}"
[[ ${RC} -gt 0 ]] && exit ${RC} || true
```