# How to get the number of failed Ansible tasks and pass it to the next Bash command?

Tags: bash, ansible

I perform the deployment to production servers with Ansible and I want to implement some logic around it.

I have a Bash script that looks something like that:

```bash
# deploy to the first set of servers
ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i inventory.yml --limit "*.dc1.com"

# deploy to the second set of server
ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i inventory.yml --limit "*.dc2.com"
```

And I want to abort the execution of the second command in the case when the first Ansible command has more than 5 failed servers (more than 5 failures on some particular task). In order to do this I need to somehow get the number of task failures from `ansible-playbook` command.

Is any way to do this except parsing output of Ansible command?

Comment: I wasn't able to find any concrete documentation about that case, but you may want to purposefully fail one or two hosts, and then `- debug: var=vars` at the end of the playbook and see if the failure count is stored somewhere that's just not documented

Comment: @mdaniel Nice idea. Thanks. I will try.

Comment: Couldn't you `ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i inventory.yml --limit "*.dc1.com" && ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i inventory.yml --limit "*.dc2.com"` and then rescue the tasks when you have an acceptable failure ratio? This way your whole `ansible-playbook` command would fail or not based on the rescue logic you implement.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I can't find how I can get the failure ratio (or just the amount of failed hosts in a task). Do you have any info that can help?

Comment: "_Is any way to do this except parsing output of ansible command?_", yes, of course. It depends on ... a lot of information you haven't provided. One idea you could get from [How do I summarize the failed assertions in Ansible Tower at the end of execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76283921/6771046).

Comment: Another idea can be found under [Capture Return Code of task as Exit Code for Ansible Playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63961758/6771046).