# How do I summarize the failed assertions in Ansible Tower at the end of execution?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, assertion

I am running around 20-30 assertions in my Ansible Playbook. By ignoring errors I could run all of these without skipping. However, if any random 2-3 assertions are failed then I have to search through logs to see the details.

Is there any way I could summarize the failed assertions at the end of execution?

P.S. I may not be in a position to write a custom Python plugin and prefer any built-in modules to do this.

Comment: Instead of describing your actual code with words, could you share a [mre], with the actual `assert` task and the relevant logs you are talking about.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you understand under summarize failed assertions? Should the just become counted? Or do you like to have a list with a index and which assertion failed? Should the summary include the details why the assertions failed?

Answer (score 3):

It is not really clear if you are having tasks in-between those assertions or not, but if you are roughly running a bunch of assertions at the end of the playbook, you could actually run them in a `loop` — because if you have all the assertions in a list under the parameter `that`, the whole assertion will end at the first failure — so, you can register all their return at once.

And then have a conditional `fail` task that would highlight the failed assertions if there are any in the results list.

For example:

```yaml
- assert:
    that: "{{ item }}"
    quiet: true
  ignore_errors: true
  loop: "{{ _assertions }}"
  vars:
    _assertions:
      - "'a' == 'a'"
      - "'a' == 'b'"
      - "'b' == 'b'"
      - "'b' == 'a'"
  register: assertions

- fail:
    msg: >-
      Failed result:

      {% for assertion in assertions.results if assertion.failed %}
        - {{ assertion.msg }}: '{{ assertion.assertion }}'
      {% endfor %}
  when: assertions.results | selectattr('failed') | length
```

Would yield

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: |-
    Failed result:
      - Assertion failed: ''a' == 'b''
      - Assertion failed: ''b' == 'a''
```

---

If you do have tasks in-between, you can still do it, but you'll have to register each assertions and, then, join all the list of results of the different assertions together:

```yaml
- assert:
    that: "{{ item }}"
    quiet: true
  ignore_errors: true
  loop: "{{ _assertions }}"
  vars:
    _assertions:
      - "'a' == 'a'"
      - "'a' == 'b'"
  register: assertions_1

# I am just an dummy example of a task in-between
- meta: noop

- assert:
    that: "{{ item }}"
    quiet: true
  ignore_errors: true
  loop: "{{ _assertions }}"
  vars:
    _assertions:
      - "'b' == 'b'"
      - "'b' == 'a'"
  register: assertions_2

- fail:
    msg: >-
      Failed result:

      {% for assertion in assertions if assertion.failed %}
        - {{ assertion.msg }}: '{{ assertion.assertion }}'
      {% endfor %}
  when: assertions | selectattr('failed') | length
  vars:
    assertions: "{{ assertions_1.results + assertions_2.results }}"
```